# How to manually compile make in a live session w/o internet?

Tags: drivers, live-usb, offline

I need to install a Wi-Fi driver in a live session, but it does not come with "make".

How can I install make so I can install the driver, without internet?

Comment: This is an information-free Question. What OS, release, hardware, WiFi hardware, ...? Did you build your boot medium with persistent storage? Read https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: To *compile* `make` you'd first need to install a compiler. Before you go down that rabbit hole, look at installing the `make` package offline - see for example [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: @waltinator Sorry about that, I didn't think it was relevant. It's a 20.04 live session on a usb stick that needs the rtl88x2bu driver for a realtek wifi chip (https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu). I do not think it has persistent storage, as I haven't done anything to it after creating it.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.